# Calculate lorentz force on a surface?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetostatics

I know the equation $$\vec F=q(\vec u\times\vec B)$$

If current I is flowing through a circular surface and that current creates a magnetic field in that surface what is the force F exerted on the surface at a distance r from its center?

Seeing the notes I need to find dF and integrate. How do I find dF though? I know that I is uniformly distributed, that means J is fixed. I proved the following: $$I'=Jπr^2=Iπr^2/πR^2$$ $$ B=\frac{μIr}{2πR^2} $$ It seems I can write everything in terms of r but I can't continue. 
Also don't know where to write $dI, dB$ or $dr$ . If I write everything in terms of r won't I get a $dr$ anywhere the formula has $r$? That will give me $d^3r$ in the $dF$ equation. Shouldn't I have just a $dr$?

The notes also use the $F=BIL$ but it's not just a length here, it's an area.

Anyway, how do I find the lorentz force on a surface? I think my problem lies there.That or I just don't understand what I 've been asked to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what the surface relates to. You cannot have in nature a current going through a circular surface on its own. If it is a finite cylinder, then you must integrate using Biot-Savart's law, knowing that the magnetic field is only on the same plane when taken at points on the symmetry plane of the cylinder. If it's an infinite cylinder, the field is circular around the cylinder and depends on the radius. Because of the symmetry, you would use Ampere's law to calculate the magnitude.

EDIT:

[image: Picture]

Comment: The field is given by the equation I wrote for r<R(inside the cylinder) and that was found by using Ampere's Law.That's definitely right up to this point because I checked my answer notes. It's when we calculate the force that I lose it. He uses dF=dI(dl x B).

Comment: That assumes that the current which generates the magnetic field creates a force on itself, which is incorrect. When taking the force, one assumes a different current at the point where the magnetic field of the first is taken. However, if you wanted to solve this as a mathematical abstraction, assuming B is external and the current is what B acts on, then you use the force formula for a differential unit of current and integrate along the curve to find the resultant force. dF=dq(Vdq x B). dq*Vdq=dq*(dr/dt)=(dq/dt)*dr. dr is a vector. Therefore dF=I(dr x B), assuming constant current I.

Comment: That's good to know at the end, thanks. As for the above, those were my thoughts exactly. Let's take a point at a distance r from the center of the circle. There will be a magnetic field B at that point created by the current going through our surface at distances closer than r. To put it differently, I divide my conductor into to cylinders. The inside one creates a B field in the area remaining for R>r. Isn't that possible? That's the only way I thought and made sense.

Comment: This has to do with cylindrical and spherical symmetry. It can be proven that the electric field inside an infinite cylinder with a cylindrical cavity in it has a symmetry such that all contributions inside are cancelled. The same can be said of a charged sphere with a spherical concentric cavity in it. It can be proven mathematically, but it is intuitive that the symmetry would cancel out the field. If there is no electric field, there cannot be any magnetic field. Therefore in both cases there is only a field outwards, never inside. This isn't true for finite cylinders due to border effects.

Comment: This knowledge of symmetry, which in more depth also gives you the direction of the field, is a prerequisite to using Gauss's and Ampere's law. We use these laws in infinite objects and closed objects like spheres, because the symmetry allows us to find the constant direction (and/or no field inside) and the integral is easy to solve. For finite objects, the laws still apply, but they are not useful because the direction of the field is not known beforehand, and the integral then becomes unsolvable. Hence we integrate these cases directly from the definition of electrical and magnetic fields.

Comment: http://physics.bu.edu/~duffy/semester2/c15_inside.html This is what I found and got more confused

Comment: Compute the current function. You will see that it is a piecewise function, because it grows until you get to the end of the cylinder and then it's constant outside. The circulation of B along amperian curves is always the same, and a function of r: B*length = B*2*pi*r. Hence you apply Ampere's law in both regions of the piecewise function, and you will find that B is also obviously a piecewise function.

Comment: I just edited my answer to compute what is not well-explained in that page.